# error CS1061: 'DataBase' I wrote the code according to the guide, everything is correct. But I get an error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm writing C# code for Unity. I wrote a guide on You tube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H076jHJzAJw&t=0s
I have a problem in all the lines where I use data.

example of a line where it shows an error:(I cut the lines from different places in the code)

> Assets\Scripts\Inventory.cs(36,47): error CS1061: 'DataBase' does not contain a definition for 'items' and no accessible extension method 'items' accepting a first argument of type 'DataBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

the document that I will refer to later is also called DataBase

```
public DataBase data;

AddItem(i,data.items[Random.Range (0, data.items.Count)],Random.Range (1,99));
```

same error, but different lines:

```
items[id].itemGameObj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = data.items[invItem.id].img;
items[i].itemGameObj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = data.items[items[i].id].img;

movingObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = data.items[currentItem.id].img;

AddItem(currentID, data.items[0], 0);
```

DataBase file:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class DataBase : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<Item> item = new List<Item>();
    }

        [System.Serializable]

    public class Item
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public Sprite img;
        public int cost;
        public int kolvo;
    }
```

googled, didn't find similar situations

Comment: *"Everything is correct but I get an error"*? No, if you get an error, obviously not everything is correct!

Comment: Well, the error is pretty self-explaining: *"DataBase' does not contain a definition for 'items'"*.  You have a class `DataBase` which does not contain a public member called `items`. Note that C# is case sensitive. Is the member called `Items` with an upper case `I`? Or is it not public?

Comment: Could you show us your `DataBase` implementation?

Comment: there are no errors - I meant that I rechecked all 6 parts of the lesson and did not find a typo in my code. And the person from the video has everything working. And with i b I it should be so. this is not a typo, but other variables. DataBase will be added now

Answer (score 1):

As always in programming, error messages are usually pretty self-explanatory and you need to read them carefully. Have a look at your first example:

```
public DataBase data;

AddItem(i,data.items[Random.Range (0, data.items.Count)],Random.Range (1,99));
```

Here, you are calling `data.items`. But if you look at `DataBase` there is no `items`, just `item`. You probably made a typo and your class `DataBase` should probably look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
}

    [System.Serializable]

public class Item
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public Sprite img;
    public int cost;
    public int kolvo;
}
```

In particular, look at the line `public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();` where I added an **s**.

Comment: Thank you very much! the second file with the code is large and I double-checked every line of it 2-3 times, I'm small, I didn't even think about it, the problem is in it. thanks again. and I also translated the error 20 times, but I'm not a coder, just a game artist and we had to make a simple game at the university. thank you again very much for your help